# Naudio WaveFileReader.Read() doesn't fill the byte[] buffer

Tags: c#, naudio

```
Console.WriteLine("Audio file path : " + audioFilePath);
NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader reader = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(audioFilePath);
Console.WriteLine("Reading file of length : " + reader.Length);
byte[] buffer = new byte[reader.Length];
Console.WriteLine("created buffer of size : " + buffer.Length);
reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Console.WriteLine("data read to buffer : " + readBuffer(buffer));
```

The above code outputs

```
Audio file path : C:\Users\Me\Desktop\testAudio.wav
Reading file of length : 12349440
created buffer of size : 12349440
```

If I change the line

```
Console.WriteLine("data read to buffer : " + readBuffer(buffer));
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine("data read to buffer");
```

the output becomes

```
Audio file path : C:\Users\Me\Desktop\testAudio.wav
Reading file of length : 12349440
created buffer of size : 12349440
data read to buffer
```

---

readBuffer() is just

```
public static string readBuffer(byte[] buffer)
        {
            string stringResult = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                stringResult += buffer[i];
            }
            return stringResult;
        }
```

---

If I remove the console printing of the buffer, the execution hangs at whichever line uses the buffer, in this case next in line is `Convert.ToBase64String();`

Any ideas ?

Comment: Testing with a smaller uncompressed file revealed it worked, but I don't know if it's a matter of file size or a matter of compression. Either way, I need to solve it

Comment: It did take some time to compute though.